# Searchable Dropdown list in Asp.net and Jquery (styling)

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, dropdown

I have followed this tutorial http://www.fourthbottle.com/2015/03/how-to-create-searchable-dropdown-list.html, dropdown is working fine but the text is getting out of textbox.

How can I fix it?

[image]

/* JQuery Searchable DropDown Plugin */

```
(function($) {
    var B = register("searchable");
    B.defaults = {
        maxListSize: 100,
        maxMultiMatch: 50,
        exactMatch: false,
        wildcards: true,
        ignoreCase: true,
        warnMultiMatch: "top {0} matches ...",
        warnNoMatch: "no matches ...",
        latency: 200,
        zIndex: "auto"
    };
    B.execute = function(g, h) {
        var j = null;
        var k = null;
        var l = null;
        if ($.browser.msie && parseInt(jQuery.browser.version) < 7) return this;
        if (this.nodeName != "SELECT" || this.size > 1) return this;
        var m = $(this);
        var n = {
            index: -1,
            options: null
        };
        var o = "lang";
        var p = false;
        $.browser.chrome = /chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
        if ($.browser.chrome) $.browser.safari = false;
        if ($.meta) {
            g = $.extend({}, options, m.data())
        }
        var q = $("<div/>");
        var r = $("<div/>");
        var t = $("<input/>");
        var u = $("<select/>");
        var x = $("<option>" + g.warnMultiMatch.replace(/\{0\}/g, g.maxMultiMatch) + "</option>").attr("disabled", "true");
        var y = $("<option>" + g.warnNoMatch + "</option>").attr("disabled", "true");
        var z = {
            option: function(a) {
                return $(u.get(0).options[a])
            },
            selected: function() {
                return u.find(":selected")
            },
            selectedIndex: function(a) {
                if (a > -1) u.get(0).selectedIndex = a;
                return u.get(0).selectedIndex
            },
            size: function(a) {
                u.attr("size", Math.max(2, Math.min(a, 20)))
            },
            reset: function() {
                if ((m.get(0).selectedIndex - 1) == m.data("index")) return;
                var a = m.get(0).selectedIndex;
                var b = m.get(0).length;
                var c = Math.floor(g.maxMultiMatch / 2);
                var d = Math.max(1, (a - c));
                var e = Math.min(b, Math.max(g.maxMultiMatch, (a + c)));
                var f = a - d;
                u.empty();
                this.size(e - d);
                for (var i = d; i < e; i++) u.append($(m.get(0).options[i]).clone().attr(o, i - 1));
                if (e > g.maxMultiMatch) u.append(x);
                u.get(0).selectedIndex = f
            }
        };
        draw();
        var A = false;
        r.mouseover(function() {
            A = true
        });
        r.mouseout(function() {
            A = false
        });
        u.mouseover(function() {
            A = true
        });
        u.mouseout(function() {
            A = false
        });
        t.click(function(e) {
            if (!p) enable(e, true);
            else disable(e, true)
        });
        t.blur(function(e) {
            if (!A && p) disable(e, true)
        });
        m.keydown(function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode != 9 && !e.shiftKey && !e.ctrlKey && !e.altKey) t.click()
        });
        m.click(function(e) {
            u.focus()
        });
        u.click(function(e) {
            if (z.selectedIndex() < 0) return;
            disable(e)
        });
        u.focus(function(e) {
            t.focus()
        });
        u.blur(function(e) {
            if (!A) disable(e, true)
        });
        u.mousemove(function(e) {
            if ($.browser.opera && parseFloat(jQuery.browser.version) >= 9.8) return true;
            var a = Math.floor(parseFloat(/([0-9\.]+)px/.exec(z.option(0).css("font-size"))));
            var b = 4;
            if ($.browser.opera) b = 2.5;
            if ($.browser.safari || $.browser.chrome) b = 3;
            a += Math.round(a / b);
            z.selectedIndex(Math.floor((e.pageY - u.offset().top + this.scrollTop) / a))
        });
        r.click(function(e) {
            t.click()
        });
        t.keyup(function(e) {
            if (jQuery.inArray(e.keyCode, new Array(9, 13, 16, 33, 34, 35, 36, 38, 40)) > -1) return true;
            l = $.trim(t.val().toLowerCase());
            clearSearchTimer();
            j = setTimeout(searching, g.latency)
        });
        t.keydown(function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 9) {
                disable(e)
            }
            if (e.shiftKey || e.ctrlKey || e.altKey) return;
            switch (e.keyCode) {
                case 13:
                    disable(e);
                    m.focus();
                    break;
                case 27:
                    disable(e, true);
                    m.focus();
                    break;
                case 33:
                    if (z.selectedIndex() - u.attr("size") > 0) {
                        z.selectedIndex(z.selectedIndex() - u.attr("size"))
                    } else {
                        z.selectedIndex(0)
                    }
                    synchronize();
                    break;
                case 34:
                    if (z.selectedIndex() + u.attr("size") < u.get(0).options.length - 1) {
                        z.selectedIndex(z.selectedIndex() + u.attr("size"))
                    } else {
                        z.selectedIndex(u.get(0).options.length - 1)
                    }
                    synchronize();
                    break;
                case 38:
                    if (z.selectedIndex() > 0) {
                        z.selectedIndex(z.selectedIndex() - 1);
                        synchronize()
                    }
                    break;
                case 40:
                    if (z.selectedIndex() < u.get(0).options.length - 1) {
                        z.selectedIndex(z.selectedIndex() + 1);
                        synchronize()
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    return true
            }
            return false
        });

        function draw() {
            m.css("text-decoration", "none");
            m.css("text-decoration", "none");
            m.width(m.outerWidth());
            m.height(m.outerHeight());
            q.css("position", "relative");
            q.css("width", m.outerWidth());
            if ($.browser.msie) q.css("z-index", h);
            r.css({
                "position": "absolute",
                "top": 0,
                "left": 0,
                "width": m.outerWidth(),
                "height": m.outerHeight(),
                "background-color": "#FFFFFF",
                "opacity": "0.01"
            });
            t.attr("type", "text");
            t.hide();
            t.height(m.outerHeight());
            t.css({
                "position": "absolute",
                "top": 0,
                "left": 0,
                "margin": "0px",
                "padding": "0px",
                "outline-style": "none",
                "border-style": "solid",
                "border-bottom-style": "none",
                "border-color": "transparent",
                "background-color": "transparent"
            });
            var a = new Array();
            a.push("border-left-width");
            a.push("border-top-width");
            a.push("font-size");
            a.push("font-stretch");
            a.push("font-variant");
            a.push("font-weight");
            a.push("color");
            a.push("text-align");
            a.push("text-indent");
            a.push("text-shadow");
            a.push("text-transform");
            a.push("padding-left");
            a.push("padding-top");
            for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) t.css(a[i], m.css(a[i]));
            if ($.browser.msie && parseInt(jQuery.browser.version) < 8) {
                t.css("padding", "0px");
                t.css("padding-left", "3px");
                t.css("border-left-width", "2px");
                t.css("border-top-width", "3px")
            } else if ($.browser.chrome) {
                t.height(m.innerHeight());
                t.css("text-transform", "none");
                t.css("padding-left", parseFloatPx(t.css("padding-left")) + 3);
                t.css("padding-top", 2)
            } else if ($.browser.safari) {
                t.height(m.innerHeight());
                t.css("padding-top", 2);
                t.css("padding-left", 3);
                t.css("text-transform", "none")
            } else if ($.browser.opera) {
                t.height(m.innerHeight());
                var b = parseFloatPx(m.css("padding-left"));
                t.css("padding-left", b == 1 ? b + 1 : b);
                t.css("padding-top", 0)
            } else if ($.browser.mozilla) {
                t.css("padding-top", "0px");
                t.css("border-top", "0px");
                t.css("padding-left", parseFloatPx(m.css("padding-left")) + 3)
            } else {
                t.css("padding-left", parseFloatPx(m.css("padding-left")) + 3);
                t.css("padding-top", parseFloatPx(m.css("padding-top")) + 1)
            }
            var c = parseFloatPx(m.css("padding-left")) + parseFloatPx(m.css("padding-right")) + parseFloatPx(m.css("border-left-width")) + parseFloatPx(m.css("border-left-width")) + 23;
            t.width(m.outerWidth() - c);
            var w = m.css("width");
            var d = m.outerWidth();
            m.css("width", "auto");
            d = d > m.outerWidth() ? d : m.outerWidth();
            m.css("width", w);
            u.hide();
            z.size(m.get(0).length);
            u.css({
                "position": "absolute",
                "top": m.outerHeight(),
                "left": 0,
                "width": d,
                "border": "1px solid #333",
                "font-weight": "normal",
                "padding": 0,
                "background-color": m.css("background-color"),
                "text-transform": m.css("text-transform")
            });
            var e = /^\d+$/.test(m.css("z-index")) ? m.css("z-index") : 1;
            if (g.zIndex && /^\d+$/.test(g.zIndex)) e = g.zIndex;
            r.css("z-index", (e).toString(10));
            t.css("z-index", (e + 1).toString(10));
            u.css("z-index", (e + 2).toString(10));
            m.wrap(q);
            m.after(r);
            m.after(t);
            m.after(u)
        };

        function enable(e, s, v) {
            if (m.attr("disabled")) return false;
            m.prepend("<option />");
            if (typeof v == "undefined") p = !p;
            z.reset();
            synchronize();
            store();
            if (s) u.show();
            t.show();
            t.focus();
            t.select();
            m.get(0).selectedIndex = 0;
            if (typeof e != "undefined") e.stopPropagation()
        };

        function disable(e, a) {
            p = false;
            m.find(":first").remove();
            clearSearchTimer();
            t.hide();
            u.hide();
            if (typeof a != "undefined") restore();
            populate();
            if (typeof e != "undefined") e.stopPropagation()
        };

        function clearSearchTimer() {
            if (j != null) clearTimeout(j)
        };

        function populate() {
            if (z.selectedIndex() < 0 || z.selected().get(0).disabled) return;
            m.get(0).selectedIndex = parseInt(u.find(":selected").attr(o));
            m.change();
            m.data("index", new Number(m.get(0).selectedIndex))
        };

        function synchronize() {
            if (z.selectedIndex() > -1 && !z.selected().get(0).disabled) t.val(u.find(":selected").text());
            else t.val(m.find(":selected").text())
        };

        function store() {
            n.index = z.selectedIndex();
            n.options = new Array();
            for (var i = 0; i < u.get(0).options.length; i++) n.options.push(u.get(0).options[i])
        };

        function restore() {
            u.empty();
            for (var i = 0; i < n.options.length; i++) u.append(n.options[i]);
            z.selectedIndex(n.index);
            z.size(n.options.length)
        };

        function escapeRegExp(a) {
            var b = ["/", ".", "*", "+", "?", "|", "(", ")", "[", "]", "{", "}", "\\", "^", "$"];
            var c = new RegExp("(\\" + b.join("|\\") + ")", "g");
            return a.replace(c, "\\$1")
        };

        function searching() {
            if (k == l) {
                j = null;
                return
            }
            var a = 0;
            k = l;
            u.hide();
            u.empty();
            var b = escapeRegExp(l);
            if (g.exactMatch) b = "^" + b;
            if (g.wildcards) {
                b = b.replace(/\\\*/g, ".*");
                b = b.replace(/\\\?/g, ".")
            }
            var c = null;
            if (g.ignoreCase) c = "i";
            l = new RegExp(b, c);
            for (var i = 1; i < m.get(0).length && a < g.maxMultiMatch; i++) {
                if (l.length == 0 || l.test(m.get(0).options[i].text)) {
                    var d = $(m.get(0).options[i]).clone().attr(o, i - 1);
                    if (m.data("index") == i) d.text(m.data("text"));
                    u.append(d);
                    a++
                }
            }
            if (a >= 1) {
                z.selectedIndex(0)
            } else if (a == 0) {
                u.append(y)
            }
            if (a >= g.maxMultiMatch) {
                u.append(x)
            }
            z.size(a);
            u.show();
            j = null
        };

        function parseFloatPx(a) {
            try {
                a = parseFloat(a.replace(/[\s]*px/, ""));
                if (!isNaN(a)) return a
            } catch (e) {}
            return 0
        };
        return
    };

    function register(d) {
        var e = $[d] = {};
        $.fn[d] = function(b) {
            b = $.extend(e.defaults, b);
            var c = this.size();
            return this.each(function(a) {
                e.execute.call(this, b, c - a)
            })
        };
        return e
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Show us your code, Also if you can replicate  the issue in JSFiddle that would be better

Comment: i have added the code above

Comment: You have added the plugin script which will not be helpful to debug your issue, Post your HTML and CSS used.

Comment: the problem is because of this plugin, not because of my html or css code

Comment: if i change the value of text-indent to 5px then it works fine but I dont know how to edit it in this plugin. u can find this a.push("text-indent"); in plugin

Comment: The plugin will have a CSS file too right? Did you try looking into that?

Comment: plugin has no css file. plugin contains css within juery script. see jquery script first

Comment: This is a `min.js` file and not suitable for debugging,